# How to send a Json post request using volley in android?

Tags: android, json, post, gson, android-volley

My server takes Post request in JSON format so i have created POJO class where i set data to it and converted to JSON string using GSON (toJson() method)

I am using Volley library in my application.How to send post request using volley?
i tried the following code:

```
 Entity object = new Entity();
                        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> properties = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(7);
                        properties.put("email",email);
                        properties.put("phone",phone);
                        properties.put("passwd",password);
                        properties.put("name",username);
                        properties.put("crycode","IN");
                        object.setType(EntityType.USER);
                        object.setProperties(properties);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();


                        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                        String url = "my server URL";
 GsonRequest<RegisterResponse> myReq = new GsonRequest<RegisterResponse>(
                                com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,
                                url,
                                RegisterResponse.class,
                                gson.toJson(object),headers,
                                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                                createMyReqErrorListener());

                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(myReq);
```

As my server takes request in JSON format do i need to convert the JSON string again into JSON object or the string i converted is sufficient? and how to send the request now?

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO class should look something like this:

```
    public class Entity {
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String passwd;
    private String name;
    private String crycode;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCrycode() {
        return crycode;
    }

    public void setCrycode(String crycode) {
        this.crycode = crycode;
    }
}
```

Please see i ignored userType you can add that too. And then finally give it to Gson it will convert this Class to JSON String.